# Opening a Submenu on Column Hover

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, hover, submenu

I currently have a submenu contained within a column that opens when you hover over the top menu item, but I would like for it to open when you hover anywhere within the column in which it is contained.

I tried to increase the submenu size so that it covered the column, but it still only triggered when I hovered over the top menu item.

I also tried adding custom css code to a larger custom css file that went something like this:

....

/*This block works*/

```
 .treatments .bottom-images .image-col-treatments-hover:hover > div {
  background-size: 130% !important;
 }
```

/*I added this block and it does not work (menu-for-your-face is the ul id of the menu I want to open)*/

```
.treatments .bottom-images .image-col-treatments-hover:hover .menu-for-your-face> div {
     display:block;
}
```

....